# passing array of Objects to controller fails

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to pass an array of objects to controller by ajax. so I did this

```
 var postData = {};
for (let i=0; i<@Model.Count; i++)
{
    var packageId="#z"+i+"__PackageId";
    var cartItemId="#z"+i+"__CartItemId"; 
     var childId="#childId_"+i; 
      var arobject={
             'PackageId' : $(packageId).val(),
             'CartItemId' : $(cartItemId).val(),
             'ChildId' : $(childId).val(),
              };
        postData.push(arobject);
  }

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: "application/json",
      url: '/cart/CheckEligible',
      data: JSON.stringify(postData),
      success: function (data) {}
       //something
      });
```

and I want to have it in controller

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> CheckEligible(CartDropDownV2[] cartItemDto)
    {
       //something
        return Json(null);
    }
```

but I can not have any value in cartItemDto

Comment: CartDropDownV2 have the **same** structure as the one in postData?

Comment: Try `var postData = [];` so you're pushing to an array

Comment: @J.Salas: yes exactly the same

Comment: @freedomn-m: I have test it eitherm bu tno result

Comment: Also next time , no reason to delete you previouse post with basic the same question. Just reply to it so we can help you.

Comment: @nnmmss You need to break the problem up. 1) check that you have data inside your javascript after `postData.push(arobject);` runs. 2) if you have data, make sure the model match the data.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: the answer to 1 is yes, I have correct data in postData variable
2. the model  matches the data also, I checked it again